# AreaChart in Android

Tags: android

am trying to develop an app in which i have to implement a graph..but the problem is that i dont want a line graph...but rather i want to implement a area chart graph..if i use a line graph,iam not able to colour the graph area.But in my app,i want the graph area to be coloured,and for that i need to implemnt Area Chart.
Its looks like this-
http://www.google.co.in/imgres?q=area+chart+in+excel&um=1&hl=en&sa=N&biw=1366&bih=667&tbm=isch&tbnid=vx30U9kfWKfL9M:&imgrefurl=http://www.brighthub.com/computing/

Can anyone help me on this????anyway thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

[image: Sample Image]
The picture you see is from this link :
[a chart engine](http://code.google.com/p/achartengine/downloads/list).

It's a open source.Dig the code , you'll find your solution.

Comment: @zGnep-Thanks buddy....the link you have provided is a very useful one with a lot of informations....i havenot goen through everything,but it looks like a very good area of knowledge..thanks for sharing it with me buddy